# imagemagick big stroke width adds strange effect like paint fluid

Tags: perl, imagemagick, node-imagemagick, perlmagick

I've an issue with a script named pixenate which works as a simple image editor using javascript, imagemagick and perl. After deep troubleshooting I found that the issue happens when I use a big stroke width (14+) when I draw something on an image which has some intersection, otherwise everything works fine. The issue looks like a paint fluid! as follows:

[image]

I tried turning antialias on and off, interpolate options, and method properties to all possible values in [perl magick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php).

Data sent as follows

```
[{"operation":"fetch","pxn8root":"","random":"751b","url":"http://localhost/test.jpg"},{"operation":"imagemagick","script":[["_","Draw",{"fill":"#00000000","points":"M 94.13443396226415 270.5660377358491 L 95.26179245283019 268.875 95.8254716981132 266.0566037735849 96.38915094339623 263.2382075471698 96.38915094339623 260.98349056603774 96.38915094339623 257.60141509433964 96.95283018867924 255.34669811320757 96.95283018867924 252.52830188679246 96.95283018867924 249.14622641509433 96.38915094339623 246.32783018867926 96.38915094339623 242.94575471698113 96.38915094339623 240.12735849056605 96.38915094339623 236.74528301886792 95.8254716981132 233.92688679245285 95.8254716981132 230.54481132075472 95.8254716981132 227.72641509433961 95.8254716981132 224.3443396226415 95.8254716981132 222.08962264150944 95.8254716981132 219.83490566037736 95.8254716981132 217.58018867924528 95.8254716981132 215.3254716981132 95.8254716981132 213.63443396226415 95.8254716981132 211.9433962264151 95.8254716981132 210.25235849056605 95.8254716981132 208.56132075471697 95.8254716981132 207.99764150943398 95.8254716981132 206.87028301886792 95.8254716981132 205.7429245283019 95.8254716981132 205.17924528301887 95.8254716981132 204.05188679245285 95.8254716981132 203.48820754716982 95.8254716981132 202.9245283018868 95.8254716981132 202.36084905660377 95.8254716981132 201.79716981132077 95.8254716981132 201.23349056603774 95.8254716981132 200.1061320754717 95.8254716981132 198.41509433962264 95.8254716981132 196.7240566037736 95.8254716981132 195.03301886792454 95.8254716981132 193.3419811320755 95.8254716981132 191.6509433962264 95.8254716981132 189.95990566037736 95.8254716981132 188.2688679245283 95.8254716981132 186.57783018867926 95.8254716981132 184.88679245283018 95.8254716981132 183.75943396226415 95.8254716981132 182.0683962264151 95.8254716981132 180.37735849056605 95.8254716981132 179.25 95.8254716981132 178.12264150943398 95.8254716981132 176.4316037735849 95.8254716981132 175.30424528301887 95.8254716981132 174.17688679245282 95.8254716981132 173.0495283018868 95.8254716981132 171.92216981132077 95.8254716981132 170.79481132075472 95.8254716981132 169.6674528301887 95.8254716981132 168.54009433962264 95.8254716981132 167.41273584905662 95.8254716981132 166.28537735849056 95.8254716981132 165.15801886792454 95.8254716981132 164.0306603773585 95.8254716981132 163.4669811320755 95.8254716981132 161.7759433962264 95.8254716981132 160.64858490566039 95.8254716981132 159.52122641509433 95.8254716981132 158.3938679245283 95.8254716981132 157.26650943396226 95.8254716981132 156.70283018867926 95.8254716981132 155.5754716981132 95.8254716981132 155.01179245283018 95.8254716981132 154.44811320754718 95.8254716981132 156.70283018867926 95.8254716981132 158.95754716981133 95.8254716981132 161.2122641509434 95.8254716981132 162.90330188679246 96.38915094339623 164.5943396226415 96.38915094339623 166.28537735849056 96.95283018867924 168.54009433962264 96.95283018867924 170.2311320754717 97.51650943396227 171.35849056603774 97.51650943396227 173.0495283018868 98.08018867924528 174.17688679245282 98.08018867924528 174.74056603773585 98.64386792452831 176.4316037735849 98.64386792452831 176.99528301886792 99.20754716981132 178.12264150943398 99.20754716981132 179.81367924528303 99.20754716981132 180.94103773584905 99.20754716981132 182.0683962264151 99.77122641509435 183.19575471698113 100.33490566037736 184.88679245283018 100.33490566037736 186.01415094339623 100.33490566037736 187.14150943396226 100.89858490566039 188.83254716981133 101.4622641509434 189.39622641509433 102.02594339622642 190.52358490566039 102.02594339622642 191.6509433962264 102.58962264150944 192.77830188679246 102.58962264150944 194.4693396226415 102.58962264150944 195.03301886792454 103.15330188679245 196.16037735849056 103.15330188679245 196.7240566037736 103.71698113207547 197.85141509433961 104.28066037735849 198.97877358490567 104.28066037735849 199.5424528301887 105.40801886792453 200.66981132075472 105.40801886792453 201.79716981132077 105.97169811320755 202.9245283018868 106.53537735849056 204.05188679245285 107.09905660377359 205.7429245283019 107.6627358490566 206.87028301886792 108.22641509433963 208.56132075471697 108.79009433962264 210.25235849056605 109.91745283018868 211.37971698113208 110.4811320754717 212.50707547169813 111.04481132075472 214.19811320754718 111.60849056603774 215.3254716981132 112.17216981132076 216.45283018867926 112.73584905660377 217.58018867924528 112.73584905660377 218.1438679245283 113.2995283018868 219.83490566037736 113.2995283018868 220.9622641509434 114.42688679245283 222.08962264150944 114.99056603773585 223.7806603773585 115.55424528301887 224.90801886792454 116.11792452830188 226.5990566037736 117.24528301886792 227.72641509433961 117.24528301886792 228.85377358490567 117.80896226415095 229.9811320754717 118.37264150943396 231.10849056603774 118.93632075471699 231.67216981132077 119.5 232.7995283018868 119.5 234.49056603773585 120.62735849056604 235.05424528301887 121.19103773584906 236.74528301886792 121.75471698113208 237.30896226415095 121.75471698113208 238.43632075471697 122.3183962264151 239 122.88207547169812 240.12735849056605 123.44575471698113 240.69103773584905 123.44575471698113 241.25471698113208 124.00943396226415 241.8183962264151 124.00943396226415 242.38207547169813 124.00943396226415 242.94575471698113 124.57311320754717 244.07311320754718 125.13679245283019 245.2004716981132 125.13679245283019 246.32783018867926 125.13679245283019 246.89150943396226 125.7004716981132 246.89150943396226 125.7004716981132 247.45518867924528 125.7004716981132 248.58254716981133 126.26415094339623 249.14622641509433 126.26415094339623 249.70990566037736 126.82783018867924 250.27358490566039 127.39150943396227 250.8372641509434 127.39150943396227 251.4009433962264 127.95518867924528 251.4009433962264 127.95518867924528 252.52830188679246 127.95518867924528 253.0919811320755 128.5188679245283 253.0919811320755 129.08254716981133 255.34669811320757 130.20990566037736 257.60141509433964 131.3372641509434 258.72877358490564 131.9009433962264 260.4198113207547 131.9009433962264 260.98349056603774 132.46462264150944 261.54716981132077 132.46462264150944 262.1108490566038","primitive":"path","stroke":"rgb(0, 0, 255)","strokewidth":"14"}],["_","return"]]}]
```

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16